# How to Optimaze this sql

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

One model separated by records with dates and same verification codes.
I want to select and group same records by verification code and select dates range. I wrote next sql, but his executing is to long..

```
SELECT
            (
                SELECT DATE 
                FROM user_day_status 
                WHERE VERIFICATION_TOKEN = uds.VERIFICATION_TOKEN 
                ORDER BY DATE ASC limit 1) 
                AS DATE_FROM,
            (
                SELECT DATE 
                FROM user_day_status 
                WHERE VERIFICATION_TOKEN = uds.VERIFICATION_TOKEN 
                ORDER BY DATE DESC limit 1) 
                AS DATE_TO,
        uds.USER_ID,uds.VERIFICATION_TOKEN,uds.DESCRIPTION
        FROM user_day_status uds 
        GROUP BY uds.VERIFICATION_TOKEN
```

Comment: show schema with index for table, also why the group by. oh i see you are doing min and max

Comment: Can you add an explain plan of this query?

Comment: I have model with field date from, date to and other fields. In table one models stored like many records separated by dates. I want get  as one model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do a self join at all:

Check here:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/acf12/3

Basically:

```
SELECT MIN(uds1.DATE) AS DATE_FROM, 
       MAX(uds1.DATE) AS DATE_TO,
       uds1.USER_ID,
       uds1.VERIFICATION_TOKEN,
       uds1.DESCRIPTION
  FROM user_day_status uds1
 GROUP BY uds1.USER_ID,
          uds1.VERIFICATION_TOKEN,
          uds1.DESCRIPTION
```

Answer (score 4):

Does this work for you :

```
SELECT MIN(uds1.DATE) AS DATE_FROM, MAX(uds1.DATE) AS DATE_TO, uds1.USER_ID,uds1.VERIFICATION_TOKEN,uds1.DESCRIPTION
FROM user_day_status uds1
JOIN  user_day_status uds2 ON uds1.VERIFICATION_TOKEN = uds2.VERIFICATION_TOKEN
GROUP BY uds1.VERIFICATION_TOKEN
```

Answer (score 1):

First try:

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT MIN(DATE) FROM user_day_status 
    WHERE VERIFICATION_TOKEN = uds.VERIFICATION_TOKEN 
) AS DATE_FROM, 
(
    SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM user_day_status 
    WHERE VERIFICATION_TOKEN = uds.VERIFICATION_TOKEN 
) AS DATE_TO, 
uds.USER_ID,uds.VERIFICATION_TOKEN,uds.DESCRIPTION
FROM user_day_status uds 
GROUP BY uds.VERIFICATION_TOKEN
```

and ensure there is an index over 'DATE'.